# grep/awk not returning expected result

Tags: bash, shell-script

I wrote the script below, named it `find`, and saved it in `bin`, but it's not giving the expected result.
When I execute `find TEST`, it matches all occurrences of `TEST` in all lines and provides output.
But I want my script to look for `TEST` in column 1 only.
I am using `grep` but I think it can be achieved using `awk` but I am unable to do it using `awk`.

input file:

```
DEV       RETAIL       RETAILDEVNode  
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
QA         AUDIT       AUDITQANode
PROD       SALE        SALEPRODNode
QA         SALE        SALETESTNode
QA        FINANCE      FINANCEQANode
PROD      FINANCE      FINANCEPRODNode
```

```
grep $1 inputfile`
```

output:

```
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
QA         SALE        SALETESTNode
```

expected output:

```
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

Comment: You forgot to show us the script. Also, please tell us your operating system. And when you say you saved it as `bin/find`, do you mean `/bin/find`? Or `/usr/bin/find`? Or `/home/your/username/bin/find`? Or something else? In any case, do NOT name it `find` because that will stop you from being able to use the standard `find` command to find files.

Comment: by default `grep` will search TEST string in any place in the line, the third line is match for AUDI**TEST**Node. use `grep --colout TEST inputfile` to see matched string.

Comment: Hi, pls see below script..                                                                                                         [admin@server bin]$ ls
find
[admin@server bin]$ $ cat find
grep $1 inputfile

[admin@server] find TEST

TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
QA         SALE        SALETESTNode                                                                                 expected output-                                                                       TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode

Comment: That information in a comment is all but unreadable. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736063/edit) and add it there so everything is in one place

Comment: I wouldn't name the script `find` as that is a standard utility, like `grep` or `awk`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk '$1=="TEST"' file
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

##### With [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
$ grep '^TEST ' file
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

##### With [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
$ sed -n '/^TEST /p' file
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

##### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
$ perl -ane 'print if $F[0] eq "TEST"' file
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

##### With [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby):

```
$ ruby -ane 'puts $_ if $F[0] == "TEST"' file
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

##### With pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash):

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line == TEST* ]] && echo "$line"
done < file
TEST      RETAIL       RETAILTESTNode 
TEST       AUDIT       AUDITTESTNode
```

##### Finally, using a script `find_by_first_field`

Don't use `find` as a script name:

- it will override the system `find` if `~/bin` is before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` variable
- better name it with something describing more what the script do

`cat ~/bin/find_by_first_field`

```
#!/bin/bash

exec awk -v arg=${1:?} '$1==arg' "${@:2}"
```

Usage:

```
find_by_first_field <PATTERN> <file1> [file2 file3]
```

Explanations:

- `-v arg` if the way to pass variable(s) usable by `awk` internally
- `$1` is the first field by default in `awk` (whitespace(s) and tabs delimited), don't confuse with `bash` `$1` first argument
- `arg` is the declared `awk` variable
- `${1:?}` is the first argument `$1`. Using bash *parameter expansion*, it will throw an error if the first argument is missing
- `${@:2}` `$@` is the list of arguments. `${@:2}` is the same, but starting at the seconds element, because `$1` aka first argument is already used

Comment: Thanks, pls see my above input how can i achieve this with 'find'

Comment: Take a look to the new section `find_by_first_field`

Comment: Thanks much Gilles, its working... is it possible if you can elaborate script like what awk -v arg=${1:?} and '$1==arg' "${@:2}" doing here.

Comment: Added 'Explanations' section